# How to change the Postgres hostname in pgadmin 4?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

By default, the database hostname is `localhost` after the Postgres has been installed.

Can the hostname be changed to something else like `localhost\\abc`?

If yes, how can I do it in Windows/pgadmin?

Thanks

Comment: localhost is a synonym for 127.0.0.1 and your new name must also be resoved  by the system

Comment: Hostnames [cannot contain backslashes](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc952)